# How do sri vaishnavas justify Krishna's Behaviour

Tags: krishna, dharma, ramanujacharya

Krishna's behaviour in his life was full of adharma tactics like, Running from the battlefield when fighting [Kalayavana](http://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/why-is-lord-krishna-called-ranchod) (despite being kshatriya) which in Kurukshetra he says it is not a way of kshatriya to arjuna. Now There is no justification given by Ramanujacharya on his behaviour. So how do sri Vaishnavas justify krishna's behaviour despite being an incarnation.

Comment: An incarnation of Lord Vishnu's main objective is to restore Dharma on earth by eradicating evil and which is exactly what he did.So,is justification of what he did,why he did and how he did necessary?

Comment: Are you a sri vaishnava or do you know anything about it? If no then please read their philosophical text sri bhasya by ramanujacharya where he says that Dharma is above all and even before/after sharanagati(guranteed moksha) you should follow dharma. Now if god is my whole target why shouldn’t I question to what I am surrendering to and weather the philosophy is contradictory or lord's behaviour is. Because  Ramanujacharyas commentary on Bramha sutra is best till date.

Comment: "Dharma is above all " & "Restoring/preserving Dharma is above all"..these are  the key things here.You yourself have answered your question.

Comment: are you a Sri vaishnava or how much do you know about them and their documents ? I didnt say restoring dharma without following dharma is above all. I said dharma is above all and doing karma for consequence is a sin as told by shri Krishna in shrimad bhagwad geeta. doing karma with righteousness is okay without righteousness it is sin even if consequence is good. what you are saying is like this 'I broke the law because I wanted to establish law and order'.

Comment: Your question is borderline duplicate of [Should Krishna be considered good or bad?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7710/2995) I have not read Sribhashya but you see my answer to that question [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10625/2995).

Comment: @sv. My question is different I am not judging krishna I want a particular justification from a sect according to their beliefs

Comment: Nice question. I'm *Vaishnava*, and what we have learned is, it was Krishna's *leela*. To me that answer is acceptable recently, but it's not digestable for all. I read @sv.'s answer just now and it answers your question with almost sincerity. It would be naive for sv or me or anyone to copy it Here again. In nutshell, Krishna never cared about good/bad while doing Karma, hence he was detached. Any path, rule or promise was meant to broken for him, because all are forms of attachments. "People are good as much as they are allowed to be" -- TDK

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, even the linked question came to me for marking duplicate. However, there is a rule of "at least 1 upvoted answer". Are mods allowed for it? In such case I may try to flag such other unanswered dupes.

Comment: @iammilind That "1 upvoted answer" thing is only about the close votes of ordinary users, not mods.  So yeah, if you see other pairs of unanswered questions that seem like clear duplicates, you can flag them and we'll consider it.

Comment: IMO,its extremely IMPROPER for human beings(no matter who you are and how intellectually proficient you are) to judge/discuss ,ask for clarifications/justifications of God's actions(Leelas).That God can't deviate from the path of righteousness is an accepted and understood part.although apparently it might seem the opposite.And it does not require me to become a member of a particular sect to understand this SIMPLE truth.If i'm questioning Lord's actions(his Leelas) then i'm already a long way away from the stage of surrender.

Comment: @Rickross Sorry but apparently not everyone on Hinduism.SE has reached your level to not question any God's actions. We are all human after all. Just as you do not judge God's actions, it's best we don't go after or judge users here based on their questions! Even an atheist can ask questions here!

Comment: @sv ."Even an atheist can ask questions here".I understood that part later myself.And i'll not argue any further on this point.I'll not even post comments on such questions which ask about justification of God's Leela.Although i understand that given the limitedness of our senses and our intellect we will never be able understand them(leela)fully unless we are "Realised".But i understood the point you are making quite well.So no more posts from my side of that sort.

Comment: @Rickross - Do you know what philosophy Sri vaishnavas follow? They follow Vishishtadvaita. They think that Moksha can be attained by either Bhakti yoga (jnana + worship/praise of lord shri hari) or total surrender Sharanagati. And if you have performed Sharanagati nothing not even killing a bramhana can't stop you from attaining moksha, and they also think that no matter what happens everyone including (godly incarnations) should follow dharma (even if they have perfomed sharanagati).