# Which saints or Yogis from history are recorded to have done Parakaya Pravesha successfully?

Tags: history, yoga, siddhi

Parakaya Pravesha is an advanced level Yogic Siddhi (accomplishment) obtained by certain adept Yogis. By virtue of which these Yogis can enter other's bodies.

Adi Shankaracharya mastered this Siddhi and [entered the body of a king](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15900/was-adi-shankaracharya-s-parakaya-pravesha-to-learn-kamashastra-dharmic).

I want to find out the names of more such saints and Yogis (from history and not from scriptures) who also had achieved this Siddhi and had successfully entered other's bodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibbetibaba

Tibbati Baba made his soul to permanently or temporarily enter into another human body. According to Hinduism any living human being soul can enter the body of another living or dead human being. This fact is supported by Swami Vivekananda in his book - 'Raj-Yoga or Conquering The Internal Nature'. This can be done when one meditates on the body which is to be entered.

There are two views about Tibbetibaba's parakayapravesha. The first one states that when after wandering for many years, he found that his body has grown weak; he decided to enter his soul into the body of a Tibetan Buddhist monk. The Tibetan Buddhist monk (Lama) had just entered into the state of Parinirvana.

After getting the new body (the body of the Lama) he resumed his wanderings and began making disciples.

According to another view, On his second visit to Myanmar, with the permission of the King and Queen of Myanmar, who were his great devotees, he transmigrated his soul into the body of the dead prince of Myanmar. This was done because his original body had grown weak and feeble on account of old age.

Another known saint said to have achieved the feat is Adi Shankara. He did it when Ubhaya Bharati, the wife of Mandana Mishra, challenged him to have a debate on the "science of sex-love". So to learn the practical aspects of love-making, he entered his soul into the body of a dead king for period of one month. Consequently, Ubhaya Bharati was forced to accept defeat.

But all biographies of Sri Adi Sanakara do not accept this incident.

Comment: If u can add to the answer the relevant portion from Wiki which states that he did Parakaya Pravesha then that will be better ..

Comment: Did he also know kayakalpa? Btw did u read this in one Girija Library book?

Comment: @Rickross no i didnt read girija lib bk, but this practice i think is known as kayakalpa

Comment: No Kayakalpa is getting a new body by discarding the old one ... and this is just entering others bodies .. btw hv u read the book Kalpataru Kamdhenu?

Comment: @Rickross yes yesterday night it striked me also.Babaji M, the guru of Shyamacharan Lahiri is believed to be alive till today by kayakalpa

Comment: @Rickross its believed that Thakur Sarvananda of Meher is also alive till date using kayakalpa

Comment: Ok In Kalpataru I book I read abt many Shadus who have used Kayakalpa .. they actually do that everytime they think that their present body is old .. One Sadvi looks like 16 yrs old but actually she is more than 300 yrs old .. she has done it for around 5 times ..

Comment: @Rickross yes the gyanganj sadhus are famous for this

Comment: If u can add more such Sadhus' names who hv done it then pls do.. I will wait for some more time before accepting ur answer .. to see if I get more answers

Comment: I hv accepted the answer .. But if u can add more such Yogis' names then that will be good

Comment: @Rickross Good morning. i wd try.this android app doesnt allow me to reply to chat or undelete answer mentioning at least 20 reputations are required!