# Explanation of SrimadBhagwadGita verse 18.66

Tags: scripture, krishna, bhagavad-gita

Please explain in detail what Sri Krishna wants to say in the verse `18.66` of *Srimad Bhagwad Gita* :

> १८-६६|| सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज | अहं त्वा सर्वपापेभ्यो
>   मोक्षयिष्यामि मा शुचः

Comment: See [this](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-18-62.html) page .Read the commentaries given by the various Acharyas.

Comment: And [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15840/sarva-dharman-parityejya-mamekam-sharanam-vraja-in-shiva-gita) is a similar/related question.

Comment: [Here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13889/3872) is another related question.

Comment: Visit [Gita Supersite](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/) where you can find various translations and commentaries for [Srimad BhagavadGita](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sarva-dharmān parityajya 
>   mām ekaṁ śaraṇaṁ vraja 
>   ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo 
>   mokṣayiṣyāmi mā śucaḥ
>
> Abandon all varieties of religion and just surrender unto Me. I shall deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear.

Please refer: http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/66 for full explanation by Srila Prabhupada.

Comment: Thank You. The are explanations of other scriptures too.

Comment: Upvoted Q&A to encourage you for asking & replying. However, you should put some relevant part of the link into the answer in block quotes with bit of your understanding. @bRO

Comment: Post relevant part as an answer. Links may not be answers.

Comment: a 'link to' answer is not an answer. please edit your answer with the information from the link. You can cite the link as a source but you need to provide the information in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

This verse should better be interpreted with context of other verses. The independent analysis/translation may lead to entirely different interpretation, as it was done in Indian movie *"Dharam Sankat Mein"*. Let's see in bits & pieces.

### Translation

> <sub>BG 18.66 - Abandon all *Dharma*-s [and] take surrender [only] under "Me". "I" will liberate you from all sins. Don't repent.</sub>

### Who liberates?

Here, "I" & "Me" should be interpreted as the ultimate One, rather than Krishna's personal form as discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13950/1049).
Krishna is a rare philosopher, who had represented the ultimate identity with "I". This "I" is the liberator or the liberation.

### If all "sins" are forgiven, then What about good/bad *Karma* theory?

Now if we surrender to "I", then it simply liberates us from whatever sin we have incurred! That actually contradicts with other Vedic literature, which stresses on Karma & bearing its good/bad fruits. Doesn't it challenge common sense?
Yes, it does. But it's still true.

Assume 2 planes:

1. First is material world, where we are present now. This world
   contains all existent & non-existent things; In short all
   expressible matters.
2. The other plane is "I". That's beyond existent (*sat*) &
   non-existent (*asat*) & can't be expressed. If expressed, then it's
   no more "I". Refer [Neti
   neti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neti_neti).

In plane-1, we have a perception of good Karma & bad Karma, which affects us. However in plane-2, these sins (bad deeds) & virtues (good deeds) are not accepted, rather they are treated as illusions.

> <sub>BG 5.15 - The **Omnipresent neither accepts anybody's sin nor even virtue**. Knowledge remains covered by ignorance. Thus the creatures become deluded.</sub>

### Why not to repent?

Krishna asks "not to repent/grieve", in the end of the verse.
We may think, provided that we are still in the material world, aren't we still under the spell of Karma? Won't good/bad Karma affect our past/present/future lives? If we have committed a sin then, shouldn't we worry about its repentance or *prAyaschita*.

Such repentance depends on the ignorance. Suppose, if I believe that, I have committed a sin, then I may want to do repentance. According to Gita, that's ignorance. In reality, no Karma happens by oneself. Only 3 modes of material nature (*Sattva, Rajas, Tamas*), makes all the Karma possible. Why should one repent (do *prAyaschita*), when the consciousness of oneself just resides as a witness or a consumer.

> <sub>BG 3.27 - **Actions are performed by [three] modes of [material] nature.** [Purusha] Deluded by egoism believes as, "I am the do-er".</sub>

### Relation of *Dharma* & 3 modes

The most tricky part. First of all, we should understand that [Dharma is Not religion](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/336/1049). A person can have no religion, but every entity has its own *Dharma* in material world. The "I" also has its own *Dharma*, which is supreme.
The closest single word meaning of *Dharma* is **Tendency**.

- As a citizen of society, a person tends to do something, that's *SAmAjik Dharma*.
- As a husband, person tends to do something, that's *Pati Dharma*
- As a ruler/king, person tends to do something, that's *Kshatriya Dharma*
- ...
- All these combinations defines one's own natural tendency, which is *Swadharma*

The 3 modes of material nature as discussed above, are related to *Dharma*. [BG 18.30-18.32](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10799/1049):

1. **Sattva** (Goodness): Follows *Dharma* & hence in proper alignment with all
2. **Rajas** (Passion): Doesn't know about *Dharma* & hence are misplaced
3. **Tamas** (Ignorance): Interprets *Adharma* as *Dharma* & hence are opposite

Everyone has these 3 modes present within them except the "I". "I" is beyond these 3 modes. So, *Dharma* is a strong & easy tool for *SAtvika* people towards liberation. But there is no specific requirement that *SAtvika* people will get quicker liberation/*Moksha* compared to *RAjasika* or *TAmasika*.
For example, ShishupAla who had spent his life in ravaging innocent people got liberation as discussed in [SabhA parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02044.htm). Similarly Kansa, who killed innocent infants by throwing them to a wall, also got Moksha. Both of them showed *Tamas* qualities. There might be back-story explanations of these 2 (e.g. Jaya-Vijaya), but this is a neutral point of view. Similar can be said about RAvana as well, who was *RAjasika* (a *Rakshasa*).

### Why to abandon All *Dharma*-s

Arjuna was born with *Daivi Sampada* (Divine Quality) as he was predominantly *SAtvika*. As noted in Shankara's commentary, the Gita was said with respect to Arjuna representing the humanity.

> Arjuna is not alified for steadfastness in Knowledge through monasticism in the primary sense. Still, the Gita being meant for mankind as a whole, monasticism is spoken of here by accepting Arjuna as a representative man.

Now, ***Sattva* or "following of Dharma" also refrains a person from liberation. It holds a *Purusha* within material nature by knowledge & happiness!** This is a rare caveat found in Gita and this is the primary reason for abandoning all *Dharma* to be able to merge with the supreme/"I".

> <sub>BG 14.5,6,7,9 — O might armed, the modes of Sattva, Rajas & Tamas generated from Prakruti, binds the embodied Indivisible (Atman) into (subtle) body. — **O sinless, Due to purity, the Sattva is illuminating & distortionless. It binds with happiness & with knowledge.** — O son of Kunti, know that Rajas is generated from self-desire & thirst (to achieve). That binds the embodied (jeeva) with Karma. — O Bharata, know Tamas to be born from ignorance. It binds all bewildered embodied (jeeva) with enjoyment, laziness, sleep.</sub>

Though Krishna followed *Dharma* all his life, he never refrained from breaking stereotype whenever needed. As discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11114/1049), he didn't allow *Sattva* to overcome him. Rather he remained beyond 3 modes.

Still, *sattva* is foundation for any good society and many people follow it for smooth liberation. Treat *Dharma* as a boat in the river like life. Once you reach the other side of the river, where the "I" abodes, leave the boat!