# Is scolding or insulting someone a sin?

Tags: sin

Is scolding, insulting someone a sin ? what punishments will we face for this ?

If someone insults us, is it right to insult them back or is it better to leave to God?

Comment: "What punishment will we face?" He says- Why do you want to bear someone's sin, by insulting them? That is, Gurudeva says- Do not insult because by doing so, you get their Papam. It means thus- You get an equal amount of sin that the person is already bearing.

Comment: Last question. "Should we insult back or leave on God?" He did not particularly say - Do not insult back and leave to God. But He did say this- Let anyone do any amount of sin in front of your eyes, but do not step ahead to punish them(unless your GuruDeva asks you to do). He further says- Leave the punishment task on God. You do not do God's task.

Comment: Scolding which leads to someone's shame or insult should definitely be avoided. But yes, like parents scolding their children to teach them, this scolding is fine. Only take care that you do not harm the child(of course)

Comment: "Is scolding or insulting sin?" GuruDeva says- 'Never at all, in any circumstances, insult anyone. It is very very sinuous.' I have heard it from a very very trustworthy GuruDeva on TV. For copyright and identity issues, I am not posting His name.

Comment: @AnuragSingh, I agree with your opinion about not insulting..
but wonder why would a 'guru' worry about copyright issues

Comment: @ram Copyright issues are not necessarily meant. But identify issues do matter. The "GuruDeva" is a famous Guru and His program comes on TV. Though it's nothing wrong to tell His name. But on my part I feel I should not advertise His name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If someone insults us, is it right to insult them back?**

The Mahābhārata says (quoting from [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13971) answer):

> यस्मिन् यथा वर्तते यॊ मनुष्यस; तस्मिंस तथा वर्तितव्यं स धर्मः
>
> मायाचारॊ मायया वर्तितव्यः; साध्व आचारः साधुना परत्युदेयः
>
> yasmin yathā vartate yo manuṣyas; tasmiṃs tathā vartitavyaṃ sa dharmaḥ
>
> māyācāro māyayā vartitavyaḥ; sādhv ācāraḥ sādhunā pratyudeyaḥ
>
> One should treat another as the latter does to him. A deceitful person should be thwarted with deceit, while an honest man should be treated with honesty.

Comment: @SreeCharan The Sanskrita lines that are in the answer have a lot of spelling and Sandhi mistakes. So I request you thus- Kindly correct the verse lines. SreeCharan I hope you see this- concern to retain Sanskrita's correctness. It is important to maintain Sanskrita as it were. Sanskrita language by its nature can never be contaminated. Thus it is our duty- saving Sanskrita.